# Sending an HTTP GET request xcode

Tags: xcode, http, get, request

I'm trying to send the content of a contact form to my webservice.
My code is based on a StackOverFlow topic named : Sending get method in Xcode .

I think i follow the rules but it still doesn't work. I don't want u to lose your time, but i'm starting to get mad.

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender{


NSString *get = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"&Contact%%5BFirstName%%5D=%@+First&Contact%%5BLastName%%5D=%@+Last&Contact%%5BMail%%5D=%@&Contact%%5BPhone%%5D=%@&Contact%%5BMotivations%%5D=%@&Contact%%5BCommentaires%%5D=%@",prenomtxtfield.text,nomtxtfield.text,emailtxtfield.text,teltxtfield.text,pvController.mail.motiv,questiontxtview.text];


NSData *getData = [get dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *getLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [getData length] ];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx.zfort.net/index.php?r=site/contactAdd"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:getLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:getData];
```

My fields are : Last Name , First Name , Mail, Phone , Motiv, Question .
My webservice addr is : http://xxx.zfort.net/index.php?

Thank you all (even you're not responding... you've all already helped me in the past with your comments)

PS: it may be an issue of encoding values ?

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Nothing.. the webservice shows no add contact, and when i tried to get a response with this :

    NSURLResponse *response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

    NSData *serverReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    
    NSString *replyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[serverReply bytes] length:[serverReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"reply string is :%@",replyString);

replyString is empty

Comment: Have you tried to track the request and response with something like charlesproxy.com? That way you could check, how far your request gets or what the response exacly look like. If you then don't get any response at all, your request or the server is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should either change the method to "POST" or

1. append your get arguments to the url parameter
2. set content-length to 0 and set http body to nil

Comment: Hmmm i let the GET method, (because the webservice is that way) plus
     
    NSString *get = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://imassa.zfort.net/index.php?r=site/contactAdd&Contact%%5BFirstName%%5D=%@+First&Contact%%5BLastName%%5D=%@+Last&Contact%%5BMail%%5D=%@&Contact%%5BPhone%%5D=%@&Contact%%5BMotivations%%5D=%@&Contact%%5BCommentaires%%5D=%@",prenomtxtfield.text,nomtxtfield.text,emailtxtfield.text,teltxtfield.text,pvController.mail.motiv,questiontxtview.text];

and did 1. and 2.
Still nothing .
PS : how am i not getting any response ? 
Thank you vm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString * sendstring=[NSString StringWithFormat:@"http://xxx.zfort.net/index.php?r=site/contactAdd&Contact%%5BFirstName%%5D=%@+First&Contact%%5BLastName%%5D=%@+Last&Contact%%5BMail%%5D=%@&Contact%%5BPhone%%5D=%@&Contact%%5BMotivations%%5D=%@&Contact%%5BCommentaires%%5D=%@",prenomtxtfield.text,nomtxtfield.text,emailtxtfield.text,teltxtfield.text,pvController.mail.motiv,questiontxtview.text];

[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sendstring]] delegate:self];
```

Then you haven to implement

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

and

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

from

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html