# How to download things without display hanging?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, download

Okay. So I'm creating this app and I'm really happy with it apart from one thing. It uses a lot of internet database checking etc. and every time it does this it hangs until it has finished, spoiling the fluidity of the interface. Is there anyway to avoid this? Download stuff happens when you click a button or sometimes just as a result of an NSTimer. I would love for the user to be able to go through the interface fluidly and the app to update the info when it gets there. IS there anyway to do this?

EDIT - Current Synchronous code:
This is to download a CSV file:

```
NSString *link=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=%@&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback",timer.userInfo];
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:link];
NSData *dl=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This is to download a png file into a webView:

```
NSString *link=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=%@&t=GOOG&q=m",self.Input.text];
url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:link];
[self.graph loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Comment: Threads, GCD... Read some stuff about this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're making synchronous requests.  You shouldn't be doing that on the main thread.  Your best option is probably to switch to asynchronous requests.  You could make synchronous requests on a background thread, but that's more complicated and unnecessary in most situations.

Comment: You may want to look at AFNetworking to do asynchronous calls, or NSURLConenction's `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`

Comment: Just googeled synchronous downloading. Yes this does seem to be the problem. But how to fix it? I have little to no experience with threads. Would really appreciate an example piece of code, to demonstrate how this is done...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249662/sending-an-http-get-request-xcode/12255943#12255943

Comment: apple16. In that answer you linked, do I need the response method? I'm not using any server responses. Also I presume the method that has a NSData parameter will return the data I need?

Comment: Is there anyway to see what URL etc was used to get the NSData, so I know what to do with it?

Comment: The web view should be fine, that loads asynchronously in all cases.  [This article](http://akosma.com/2010/05/28/initwithcontentsofurl-methods-considered-harmful/) has a little background on why it's so bad to use methods like `initWithContentsOfURL:`.  You can access the initial request (which contains the original URL) through the `connection` parameter passed to your delegate method.

Comment: Thank you! All I need to know now is how to get the URL from the NSURLConnection. I just googled it and apparently [NSURLConnectionVariable currentRequest]; returns a string of the URL? Is this right?

Comment: Is there anyway to get what method it was done in or somehow add a piece of meta data, so I know why it was requested?